# Remove part of value in column

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe with the following two columns:

```
RSID rs12345. rs3984. rs12398432. rs79372.  etc   
ALLELE A. C. T. G. etc
```

Now I need to remove the . after each value in the RSID- and ALLELE-column.

I tried this option:

```
df$RSID[df$RSID == "."] <- " "

df$ALLELE[df$ALLELE == "."] <- " "
```

But unfortunately it did not work. Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we want to remove the last character that is a dot (`.`), we can either use `sub` or `substring`.  Loop over the columns of interest, match with `.` at the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blanks (`""`)

```
df[c("RSID", "ALLELE")] <- lapply(df[c("RSID", "ALLELE")], function(x) sub("\\.$", "", x))
df
#        RSID ALLELE
#1    rs12345      A
#2     rs3984      B
#3 rs12398432      C
#4    rs79372      D
```

Or a faster option is with `substr` to keep all the characters except the last one.

```
df[c("RSID", "ALLELE")] <- lapply(df[c("RSID", "ALLELE")], 
                       function(x) substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(RSID = c("rs12345.", "rs3984.", "rs12398432.", "rs79372."),
        ALLELE = paste0(LETTERS[1:4], "."), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```